# Connect to containerd (or other CRI-compatible container runtime) containers in VS Code Remote Containers extension

Tags: vscode-remote

Kubernetes is deprecating Docker as a container runtime after v1.20, so now there is more and more servers, using other container runtimes (containerd, CRI-O) instead of Docker.

But [Visual Studio Code Remote - Containers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) extension doesn't see containers, that using runtime other than Docker.

Is it possible to add support for other container runtimes to `VS Code Remote Containers` extension?

Comment: Seems not possible at now, so I fill a feature request: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6014